# How to make PuTTY to pass Ctrl-PgUp and Ctrl_PgDown through the ssh?

Tags: windows, putty

Currently in putty it is used to scroll scrollback buffer like mouse wheel. But, if mouse wheel events is passed to ssh server, when needed ( in vim for ex.), the Ctrl-PgUp is not.

Even when I set scrollback buffer size to 0, these key strokes are still invisible on the other side of the ssh connection.